# Creating 2 - 4 children from forking

Tags: c, fork

I'm still new to forking and I'm looking to create between 2-4 child process depending on the number of command line arguments. The output I'm getting is very confusing for me, and I'm not sure if I'm doing this quite right, if I am, could someone explain why the output is the way that it is?

```
 for (int i = 2; i <= argc; i++) {    //argc c is <=6

    Player *player = malloc(sizeof(*player));

    game->numPlayers = argc - 2;


    // Fork and grab the pid (modify childPid global)
    // -1 failed, 0 child, otherwise parent.
    game->pid = fork();

    if(game->pid == 0) {
         printf("From parent\n");
    } else {
        printf("From child\n");

    switch (childPid = game->pid) {
            // There was an error with fork(), quit and tell the user
        case -1:
            exit_prog(EXIT_BADSTART);
            break;
            // Create the child
        case 0:
            create_player(&game, player, i);
            break;
            // Create the parent
        default:
           // create_parent(game);
            break;
        }
    }
}

From child
From child
From parent
From parent
From child
From parent
From child
From child
From parent
From child
From parent
From child
From parent
From parent
```

Comment: where is `From child` and `From parent` printed?  May I suggest you add `getpid()` when printing, it would be easier to find out which process is doing what.

Comment: It's in the code... My understanding of this was if you wanted to make x children, you loop x times in a loop.

Comment: @user3603183: if you loop x times, you wil get (2^x) - 1 children

Comment: It seems that after the 1st child finishes calling `create_player()`, it will continue the for loop and becomes a parent, too.  So you are getting more `From parent` messages than you want.

Answer (score 1):

After **fork** statement both parent and child execute in separate threads. You are getting "From parent" and "From child" 7 times. So , I guess your argc is 4. Both parent and child start executing from the next line after **fork**.

```
For i = 2
p     will print "From Parent"
c1    will print  "From child"

For i = 3
p, c1    will print "From parent"
c2, c3   will print "Form child"

For i = 4
p,c1,c2,c3     will print "From parent"
c4,c5,c6,c7    will print "From child"


Where p is parent and cx are corresponding children.
What you are missing is that chlid thread will further create more children until i > argc.

if(child) {
    printf("From child");
    break;
}

It will prevent children to continue inside loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a snippet from your code:

```
 if(game->pid == 0) {
         printf("From parent\n");
    } else {
        printf("From child\n");

    switch (childPid = game->pid) {
            // There was an error with fork(), quit and tell the user
        case -1:
            exit_prog(EXIT_BADSTART);
            break;
            // Create the child
        case 0:
            create_player(&game, player, i);
            break;
```

It is missing `}` after `printf("From child\n");`. As a result `switch` will never have value `0` (because it is in the else brach where `game->pid != 0`), and your `create_player` will never be called.

I suggest using some code formatting / indentation tool (with luck your IDE can do it), and if you get strange indentation, you know you have some problem like this.

Comment: ahaha! I didn't actually realise that was happening! I actually intentionally put the second brace at the bottom of the switch statement, now the output looks like what I expect

Answer (score 0):

If `argc` is `6`, then the loop:

```
for (int i = 2; i <= argc; i++)
{
   game->pid = fork();
}
```

will end of creating `2^5 = 32` processes, including the main process. Here's an attempt at explaining the number.

Let's transform the loop to

```
for (int i = 0; i < K; i++)
{
   game->pid = fork();
}
```

```
For K = 1, you'll get processes:

Process 1
Process 1.0

which total to 2.

For K = 2, you'll get processes:

Process 1

Process 1.0
Process 1.1

Process 1.0.1

which total to 4.

For K = 3, you'll get processes:

Process 1

Process 1.0
Process 1.1
Process 1.2

Process 1.0.1
Process 1.0.2

Process 1.1.2

Process 1.0.1.2

which total to 8.

For K = 4, you'll get processes:

Process 1

Process 1.0
Process 1.1
Process 1.2
Process 1.3

Process 1.0.1
Process 1.0.2
Process 1.0.3

Process 1.1.2
Process 1.1.3

Process 1.2.3

Process 1.0.1.2
Process 1.0.1.3

Process 1.0.2.3

Process 1.1.2.3

Process 1.0.1.2.3

which total to 16.

For K = 5, you'll get processes:

Process 1

Process 1.0
Process 1.1
Process 1.2
Process 1.3
Process 1.4

Process 1.0.1
Process 1.0.2
Process 1.0.3
Process 1.0.4

Process 1.1.2
Process 1.1.3
Process 1.1.4

Process 1.2.3
Process 1.2.4

Process 1.0.1.2
Process 1.0.1.3
Process 1.0.1.4

Process 1.0.2.3
Process 1.0.2.4

Process 1.0.3.4

Process 1.1.2.3
Process 1.1.2.4

Process 1.1.3.4

Process 1.2.3.4

Process 1.0.1.2.3
Process 1.0.1.2.4

Process 1.0.1.3.4

Process 1.0.2.3.4

Process 1.1.2.3.4

Process 1.0.1.2.3.4

which total to 32.
```

This pattern ends up creating a formula `2^N`. For `N = 5`, you end up creating a total of `32` processes.